# Different html tag but same id

Tags: html, css

Can I have two tags like a div and an ul with same id ?

Sample html code :

```
<div id="articleOptions">
    <ul id="articleOptions">
        <li>Share</li>
        <li>View</li>
        <li>Read Later</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Whould this be a valid html code ?

Comment: Nope. It's like having two cars with the same plate.

Comment: I don't know if a validator would flag it but it should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Validators do flag it. You might not care about that. But [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is not going to return an array no matter how hard you try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. `ID`'s are unique and should only be used once per document. - [source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)
You can do it, but it will not be valid.

But you can have the same `class`-name as many times that you want.

```
.articleOptions {
   // code
}
```

..or if you want the `div` and `ul` to act differently:

```
div.articleOptions {
   // code
}

ul.articleOptions {
   // code
}
```

You can validate your code here
[W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)

Comment: Hope you don't mind I added the spec link and 'per document' just to make your answer a little bit more complete.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` should be unique .... instead you can use `class`

```
div.articleOptions{
// your css
}

ul.articleOptions{
//your css
}
```